# Subversion Server Source Code

Tags: svn

Can anyone please point out to me which part of the Subversion source code does actually represent the *server* portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion's server portion relies mostly on Apache, so you are interested in the Apache SVN modules. Those are [`mod_dav_svn`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/subversion/mod_dav_svn/) and [`mod_authz_svn`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/subversion/mod_authz_svn/). The majority (but not all) of the "server" code is in [repos.c](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/subversion/mod_dav_svn/repos.c?view=markup) (and everything it includes). That's a starting point, at least.

If you are interested in learning how Subversion's server works, you'll probably want to get a good understanding of Apache, even take a look at the source there too.